# accessing nested list items and printing certain index in a irregular list

Tags: python, list

so the problem goes as the user inputs the number of lists, the number of elements per list is undefined. after getting the input print the desired index of all the list. the problem is to skip when a certain array or list doesn't have an element in the index but the next list does.
so far i tried something like this

input:
3(no of arrays or lists)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

```
a=[]
nars=input('enter the number of arrays')
nars=int(nars)
for i in range(0,nars):
    x = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    a.append(x)
print(a)
```

output:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

expected:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
[[1,1,1], [2,2,2] ,[3,3]....

Comment: What is the full output?

Comment: I think you are trying to take first element from each list and create a list, then take second element from another list and create a list and so on , you should try using `zip` and see how far you can go. It's a good idea to explain what you are trying to do. Based on your expected output, it's not *obviously* clear

Comment: sorry new here , and i cant find to edit the question . i added my expected output , and code. pls go thru and provide any easy approach. thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=[]
c=[]
nars=input('enter the number of arrays')
nars=int(nars)
for i in range(0,nars):
    x = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    a.append(x)
print(a)
for i in range(len(a[i])):
    temp=[]
    for j in range(len(max(a))):
        try:
            temp.append(a[j][i])

        except IndexError:
            continue
    c.append(temp)
print(c)
```

```
output:
1 2 3 4 5
1 2
1 2 3 4 5 6
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6]]
```

to ignore the absence of the certain index i had to give a try and catch, other than that the prog works now. will expect someone to give a easy approach thank u

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the user input is the following string:

```
nars= "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
```

You could convert to a list of integers:

```
ary = [ int(i) for i in nars.split(' ')]
```

Then define a method to slice the list upon condition (predicate):

```
def slice_when(predicate, iterable):
  i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-1:
    if predicate(iterable[i], iterable[i+1]):
      yield iterable[x:i+1]
      x = i + 1
    i += 1
  yield iterable[x:size]
```

So, you can call:

```
print(list(slice_when(lambda x,y: x>y, ary)))
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Then you can also do the following:

```
print(list(slice_when(lambda x,y: x!=y, sorted(ary))))  
#=> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7]]
```

You can join the results to get te required output.

Comment: as iam new here , couldnt tell the input correctly , its next line each array or list is typed on the next line and its not necessarily 1 -7 its just random numbers so sorting is not needed,

Comment: I showed a method that I consider useful in this case, of course a better idea of the user input is required. For example in case of  a string `"3, 4, 5, 1, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2"`, the second method can work for grouping in sub lists based on equality. For grouping based on input order, in case of random input a signal different than `x>y` is required (for example a terminator char). Please, provide an example of user input.